# problem with unwanted face appear when make new face with vertices

Tags: export, faces

my problem is when i make a face between vertices unwanted face appear these vertices not visible in blender 2.8 but after exporting mesh to fbx , obj or other  formats The faces are perfectly visible.
[image]
unwanted face when make face between vertices

[image]
nothing visible in blender cycle render

[image]
unwanted face vidible when export mesh to other formats

Comment: ngons are not always interpreted correctly. You should at least make several polygons from the one you have here so that each of them is convex.

Comment: Thank you. When I increased the number of faces, no unwanted faces appeared